# Link between cross-validation and inference

Tags: regression, t-test, cross-validation, inference

Let's consider for instance Linear Regression and let's say we obtained some $t$-stats and confidence intervals for the coefficient estimates.

Let's suppose we also split the datasets into $K$ Folds and fit the Linear Regression model on each of these folds.

Is there a link between the confidence intervals and the estimates we found in those $K$ Folds? Intuitively, it seems reasonable to me that if I obtain a narrow confidence interval for a coefficient, I expect that the coefficients I found in those $K$ folds to be close together.

Comment: I don't think there is a "link". If we are pretty sure in an estimate based on the data, then we are likely to get similar estimate results on the whole data or from k-1 folds from it. As for the CI, these will be narrow as well, because of the data.